# Get rethinkdb dump for a particular length / particular size

Tags: dump, rethinkdb

I have a rethinkdb database, which contains 100k documents on server. i want to get a dump of 500 documents or 50Mb of data to run tests on my local machine.

Is their a way that i can specify in command line / query to get dump for specific length of documents or of specific size ?

Answer (score 0):

There isn't an argument like that in the script, but you can do this yourself from one of the client languages.

Comment: Meaning @mlucy , I have hit an end-point requesting for specific amount of data that i need and store it in my local rethinkdb ?

Comment: I mean you can write `r.table('test').limit(500)` to get 500 documents in the client and then write them to your local machine.

Comment: Yeah, but was looking for a simple way.